# Android Parcelable Issue

Tags: android, object, parcelable

I had to pass a dataobject from one activity to another. The best way to do this is uing Parcelable.
The dataobject had some fields with setter and getter methods. After setting some fields and passing the object to another activity, wha tI observed is that the field values got interchanged to other field values.
The order of fields for writing to parcel and reading from parcel is the same.

```
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    out.writeInt(id);
    out.writeString(appNo);
    out.writeString(this.policyNo);
    out.writeInt((int)this.AppRcptDt.getTime());
    out.writeString(this.currentStatus);
    out.writeString(this.productCd);
    out.writeDouble(this.sumAssured);
    out.writeDouble(this.modalPremium);
    out.writeDouble(this.annualPremium);
    out.writeString(this.paymentMode);
    out.writeString(this.branchCd);
    out.writeString(this.branchName);
    out.writeString(this.insuredName);
    out.writeString(this.auraStatus);
    out.writeString(this.ownerName);
    out.writeString(this.agentCd);
    out.writeString(this.billingMode);
}

private ApplicationTrackerDO(Parcel in) {
    id=in.readInt();
    this.appNo = in.readString();
    this.policyNo = in.readString();
    this.AppRcptDt = new Date(in.readLong());
    this.currentStatus = in.readString();
    this.productCd = in.readString();
    this.sumAssured = in.readDouble();
    this.modalPremium = in.readDouble();
    this.annualPremium = in.readDouble();
    this.paymentMode = in.readString();
    this.branchCd = in.readString();
    this.branchName = in.readString();
    this.insuredName = in.readString();
    this.auraStatus = in.readString();
    this.ownerName = in.readString();
    this.agentCd = in.readString();
    this.billingMode = in.readString();
}
```

[image: difference in field values]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not the order but the data type that is not the same, from the first 4 lines you write int, string, string, int then you read int, string, string, long. I didn't check any further, you must match both order and datatype of read and write operations.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing **int**

```
out.writeInt((int)this.AppRcptDt.getTime());
```

But reading **long**

```
this.AppRcptDt = new Date(in.readLong());
```

Comment: this will fail if this.AppRcptDt is null.

Comment: i had a problem when my date variable have to be null to identicate that it isn't set (like a birthday)

Comment: That should be simple. If your date is **null** then simply write **0** instead. For example: `out.writeLong((dt == null)? 0 : dt.getTime());`

Comment: but when i read the long for a new date instance it will create a real date because [new Date(0) != null] so i can not asume if the birthday wasnt set or the user object has this date as birthday

Comment: when reading the value,if its retrieved as 0 then simply set it to null

Comment: i think you dont get what i mean:
if you provide a gui to add some historical personalities and you want to create someon that was born 1/1/1970 so the millisecounds will be 0 that means when you read this person again and set birthday to null you have an error in your system at date 1/1/1970

ok this will only happen with persons of age > 43 but it could be possible

Comment: then instead of dealing with `getTime()`, you should use `SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");` to save the `Date` object in `string` and if its not available then simply save `null` instead. The time when you read the string out from `Parcel`, if its found out as `null` then set your `Date` as null too, otherwise use the same `SimpleDateFormat` to reconstruct your date object out from string.

Answer (score 0):

my solution to provide an date object with null

```
@Override
    public void writeToParcel ( Parcel dest, int flags ) {
        dest.writeInt((birthday != null) ? 1 : 0); // is birthday set?
        dest.writeLong((birthday != null) ? birthday.getTime() : 0);
    }

    public void readFromParcel ( Parcel in ) {
        if(in.readInt() == 1) {
            birthday = new Date(in.readLong());
        } else {
            in.readLong(); // ignore stored value
            birthday = null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

java.util.Date implements Serializable:

```
public class Date implements Serializable, Cloneable, Comparable<Date> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7523967970034938905L;

    // Used by parse()
    private static final int CREATION_YEAR = new Date().getYear();

    private transient long milliseconds;
```

Use:

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeSerializable(myDateField);
}
private MyClass(Parcel in) {
    myDateField = (Date)in.readSerializable();
}
```